# Packery layout is not working as expected in meteor with react

Tags: meteor, reactjs, packery

I am using packery layout for layouting the several items. Its working fine in initial mode, but when I create new item, then that newly created item is overlap with the first item, and when I refresh the page, then its working fine.

Here is the code sample I am using while an item is rendered ..

```
    componentDidMount(){        
        $('#packery-layout').packery({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            gutter: 10
        });
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        $('#packery-layout').packery({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            gutter: 10
        });
    }
```

what I want is that, when I create a new design, then newly created design should not be overlapped with the first item.
Any clue/solution for this issue ?
Thanks.